# Regex on Windows, get the folder path of the folder UP the current one

Tags: regex, windows, command-line

I'm using a Winautomation robot to execute some task, and I need to get the path of the folder path of the previous folder. I can easyly have the current folder of execution of my robot.

To illustrate what I want :

In my variable, I have the current directory :

X:\Memento\InventairesDistrib\VerificationsInventairesDistributeurs

I want a regex to get the previous directory, so :

X:\Memento\InventairesDistrib\

Note that I could hardcode this directory in my robot, but I would like to have a more robust program, who will work even if I move my robot and folder hierarchy somewhere else.

Thank you !

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

OK I did find how to do this within Winautomation scripting langage, no need of regex finally.

Have a nice day !